# How to stop grpc c++ client from timeout?

Tags: c++, c++11, streaming, grpc

I have a grpc c++ client which is listening for a stream of responses from server, I want it to listen forever for the responses, or before shutting down send some response to server. But the client is shutting down automatically after 15secs. 
I tried to set ClientContext::set_deadline but its not working.
Here is my code:

```
ClientContext context; 
// Connection timeout in seconds 
unsigned int client_connection_timeout = 5000; 
// Set timeout for API 
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point deadline = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(client_connection_timeout); 

context.set_deadline(deadline);
std::unique_ptr<ClientReader<Tap>> reader(stub_->STap(&context, tap_request)); 

while (reader->Read(&tap_reply)) { 
std::cout<<"Response got from server: " << tap_reply.message() << " " << std::endl; 
} 
status = reader->Finish(); 
// Act upon its status. 
if (status.ok()) { 
std::cout << "rpc succeeded" << std::endl; 
} else { 
std::cout << status.error_code() << ": " << status.error_message() 
<< std::endl; 
std::cout << "RPC failed" << std::endl; 
}
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? Or what to add in code to stop it from timeout.

Comment: Did you solve this? If yes, how? Right now I am assuming that the deadline is hard stopping the context regardless of the receiving the response